# How to create table using DOM starting from a multidimensionnel array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom, multidimensional-array

[image]Hello, i wanna create an HTML table using js dom, this table should look exactly the same as the picture and souhld contain the following informations

Groupe(Or classroom), name of the student, and then put X if the student were absent in the showed date. This informations is already set in this multidimensionnel array:

var Etudiant = [

```
['1', 'Djohnny James', 'X' , ' ', '', 'X'],

['2', 'Carolina Marry', 'X' , ' ', '', 'X'],

['2' ,'Djimmy BOB', 'X' , ' ', '', 'X']
```

];

I'm still new to JavaScript i couldn't think of valid idea to do this... So anything will be so helpful

Comment: Yeah... But i have to use those methods only.. appendChild... createElement... CreateTextNode

Comment: I have to create tr and th , td using JavaScript DOM this make my head stop working hhh

Comment: again, try googling how to build a table from javascript arrays. try some code and when it doesn't work, come back here with code you've tried and ask for help

Answer (score 1):

Demo Link: https://dojo.telerik.com/AciNolOt/5

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Create table using Array</title>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: sans-serif;
        }

        .table {
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

            .table td, .table th {
                border: 1px solid #ddd;
                padding: 10px 20px;
            }

            .table th {
                background-color: limegreen;
                color: white;
            }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Groupe</th>
                <th>Nome & Prenoms</th>
                <th>21/01/2021</th>
                <th>28/01/2021</th>
                <th>04/02/2021</th>
                <th>11/02/2021</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tableBody"></tbody>
    </table>

    <script>
        var Etudiant = [
          ['1', 'Djohnny James', 'X', ' ', '', 'X'],
                ['2', 'Carolina Marry', 'X', ' ', '', 'X'],
                ['2', 'Djimmy BOB', 'X', ' ', '', 'X']
        ];

        Etudiant.map(function (node) {
            var tableBody = "<tr>";
            node.map(function (value) {
                tableBody += "<td>" + value + "</td>";
            });
            tableBody += "</tr>";
            document.getElementById("tableBody").insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", tableBody);
        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```